# How to permit all HTTP redirect in Java Spring boot security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a Java Spring Boot application that incorporates the `Spring Boot Security` in my pom.xml. However, It works when I redirect from login to my `/home`. Though when I change the page again or do a simple ajax call, I get passed a 403 error. I believe it has to do with the security and that page not having the proper access. I am looking for the best way to solve this with still keep my security intake.

**Java Security:**

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
          .formLogin()
          .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())                 // On authentication success custom handler    
          .and()
          .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");


    }
```

**Java Success Handler:**

```
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String principal = authentication.getName();

        System.out.println("Successful login: principal " + principal);
        ADID = principal;
        response.sendRedirect("/dashboard");

    }
```

**Error in Controller:**

```
Error 403 : http://localhost:8080/edit/ajax/doesSomething
```

So the `/dashboard` is the first page I get to if the login is successful, then after that the client inputs some fields and is moved to another page that calls a different URL path. It fails I assume when it calls the other paths that are not `/dashboard`

Comment: What is your Ajax call exactly(GET or POST)?

Comment: @Nasir It is a POST request

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `CSRF` token. You can disable it in the security configure but it is better you use it. See [this](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_security_csrf) site for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       .authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
       .formLogin()
       .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())            
       .and()
       .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new 
        AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
 }
```

or disable CSRF as quick fix.

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in java security. This will permit requests to any endpoint or specified ones:

```
`   
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**").antMatchers("/example/endpoint");
    }
`
```

And you can also keep your

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
```