# Spring Security with default security gives 401 for PUT and 200 for GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I developed a spring boot application with basic security. I have two endpoints with same path and different http methods. When I include basic security with default password/with password given in application.yml, the GET api/products/{id} is authenticated and  PUT api/products/{id} gives 401 unauthorized.

What is the issue with my code?
Did I miss anything understanding the Spring security?
Any links which I may have missed for spring security will be helpful?

My code snippets are as below,

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
           //Implementation

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity updateById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id,
                                                                   @RequestBody UpdateProductRequest updateProductRequest) {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Thanks in advance

Updated with the postman screenshots:
[image][image]

Comment: How does it look your security configuration? And how do you actually make those API calls - per browser, terminal etc.?

Comment: Can you check console error ? may be it's Cross Origin (CORS) issue.

Comment: @KenanGüler I have updated the question with postman calls.

Comment: @AnilNivargi The logs doesn't show any issue related to authentication.

Comment: I actually asked for your security configuration, but @CodeWalter seems to have provided you with a working one already.

Comment: @KenanGüler I didn't have any config earlier. That is what I was missing. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the screenshots though. Since you are using Spring, you might want to check these useful tutorials regarding the Spring Security: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a Csrf configuration issue.

You have to override **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

Try this..

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.httpBasic();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added it and it works now. Thank you @CodeWalter. I should still understand spring security completely.

Comment: Read this [link](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_security_csrf). You will get a good understanding

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872017/how-to-permit-all-http-redirect-in-java-spring-boot-security/60872310#60872310) question and its answer.

For more information about `CSRF` see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html) site.

Comment: Yes. It is. I have added the web security configuration to disable csrf. Thank you @Nasir. I should get more knowledge on CSRF and spring security.